# Win32 WriteFile does not return because of Antivirus

Tags: delphi, winapi, antivirus

My code is written in Delphi 7, but I don't think it plays a particular role.

I try to overwrite the content of a file with WriteFile.
It works perfectly except when writing a ".dll" file and antivirus is active.

- Opening the handle to the file is still OK.
- writing is blocked : **WriteFile function does not RETURN !!!**

The antivirus seems to prevent from overwriting in that dll.
But, the worst is that I have to reboot the PC because my app is blocked, task manager is blocked, Windows Explorer is blocked, etc.

How can I prevent this ?

Any ideas ?

Comment: On a serious note, a tad more info. What anti-virus are you using?

Comment: Sorry, but we do not have the control of end-users PC.
Issue occurs with Bitdefender.

Comment: Then don't do stuff that triggers anti-virus software to butt in. Do it the way installers do. Write the new contents to a file, possibly without the dll extension. Register a run-once to replace the dll with the new contents and request a restart.

Comment: No compiler could ever run on a machine with that AV software. I'd suggest swapping out the AV. If that leaves you with no customers then you may wish to contact the AV vendor. Unless you are writing a compiler then your program looks a lot like malware.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: We use BitDefender at work and it does usually not interfere with Delphi. But you are right, it is by far the most annoying AV solution I have ever seen. Once the current subscription runs out, we are going to move to something else and this time I will not believe in the AV test in the German c't magazine.

Comment: @dummzeuch I commend MSE to you

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I use it at home, but I cannot use it at work, it's for home use and (very) small businesses only. I would even pay for it, because I like it very much, but MS does not sell it for medium sized businesses.

Comment: @dummzeuch Sure it does. It's just under a different name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add digital signiture to the your executable, there is a less chance triggering the anti-virus. A lots delphi programs are mis-targeted by anti-virus software, D7 is worst.

Not sure what you are trying to write to a dll. Anti-virus don't like extra data outside PE.

If you just need to update a dll, try rename the old dll, and write a new file, delete the old afterwards.

Answer (score 3):

Asside from what everyone else said for how to address the AntiVirus issue, in your code you can also use overlapped I/O to set a timeout on `WriteFile()` to make sure your code does not deadlock anymore should this issue ever raise its ugly head again.  If an overlapped operation times out, you can cancel it with `CancelIo()`, and then report the issue to the user.

Comment: but WriteFile becomes asynchronous, isn't it ?

Comment: Yes, but that does not mean you have you make your calling code run asynchronously as well. You can open the file with the `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` flag, then declare an `OVERLAPPED` structure and fill it with a waitable event from `CreateEvent()`, then call `WriteFile()` as you normally would but passing the `OVERLAPPED` to it, then use `WaitForSingleObject()` to wait for the event to be signaled. If WFSO reports signaled, use `GetOverlappedResult()` to get the write result, otherwise use `CancelIo()` to abort the write and handle the WFSO error/timeout as needed.